# phpexcel save pdf using tcpdf having pdf width issue

Tags: php, phpexcel, tcpdf, mpdf

i am using php excel tcpdf render to save file as pdf. pdf can save successfully but pdf only saving as A4 size and it cuts my columns. i have many columns so i need all columns on pdf. pdf width should be auto so it can generate pdf as per number of columns given. please have a look below is my code i tried. also i included image i taken from pdf generated. you can see my pdf width is fix so my content is cut. any suggestion

```
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');


    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;

    $rendererLibrary = 'tcpdf';

    $rendererLibraryPath = '' . $rendererLibrary;

    //echo $rendererLibraryPath;
    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();


    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setTitle("PDF Test Document")
                                 ->setSubject("PDF Test Document")
                                 ->setDescription("Test document for PDF, generated using PHP classes.")
                                 ->setKeywords("pdf php")
                                 ->setCategory("Test result file");

    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowGridLines(false);

     //If used external excel file 
    $inputFile="xlsx_file/subcategory.xlsx";
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) 
    {



        $worksheet->setShowGridLines(true);
        $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A2_PAPER );
        $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A2_PAPER );
        $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
        $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
        $worksheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);


    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);



    if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
            $rendererName,
            $rendererLibraryPath
        )) {
        die(
            'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
            '<br />' .
            'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
        );
    }

    $rand = rand(1234, 9898);
    $presentDate = date('YmdHis');
    $fileName = "report_" . $rand . "_" . $presentDate . ".pdf";

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (PDF)
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the portrait visualization:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getPageSetup()
            ->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I had to deactivate the autoSize for the columns and set the width manually, like this:

```
 $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(false);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(false);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(false);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(false);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(false);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(false);

        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(20);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(14);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(15);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(14);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(18);
        $objPHPExcel ->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(9);
```

After doing that, my pdf was printed like this:
[image]

The answer might be a little late, but I hope it helps you in the future.